# jQuery not working when called into another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form on one page that we use as a tool. It's on page tool.html, in div id="tool"

Since this tool is to be shown on another page as well, I want to pull the tool in and not have to copy and paste (in case changes are done later on, this will reflect it everywhere)

Now, I have put all the jQuery functions in a separate file that I link in, so I can reuse it on many pages.

I can call in the form properly by using

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#lyristool").load("../path/tool.html #tool");
    });
    </script>
```

And I can confirm that the linked script page is loaded in properly, but it's not working at all.

Why will the linked script work on the original page, but not on the page when that whole containing div is pulled in?

Comment: Define `it doesn't work`.

Comment: Can you post some html? eg. the `<head>` part

Comment: errors in dev console? is the path correct/same for both pages?

Comment: Is the <form> tag inside or outside <div id="tool">?

Comment: Form is inside the <div id="tool">, and no error in the dev console either. Script is loading in so it't not a path/linking issue.

Comment: Can you paste your `../path/tool.html` please?

Comment: Please edit your question, add the contents of the html file from where you make the call, and add the html being called.

Comment: included the links to the code paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute this line:

```
$("#lyristool").load("../path/tool.html #tool");
```

before loading the other script. I think your binding is not working because those elements don't exist on the page at the moment of binding.

In order to be able to do that,  you should put all your binding code in a document.ready callback.

Comment: alright, I have that line before I load the linked script, and I have the entire script in a $(document).ready(function(){ and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: You send me digging and I found this that works $.getScript('script.js'); which I put in my document.ready function which loaded in the div. This only seems to work some of the time though...

Comment: I am glad you found a solution ;).

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it and it only works some of the time...what gives?

Comment: The document.ready function is executed when all the document is loaded, at this precise moment, the functions you put as callback are executed, you should debug your code, and track if it executes all those lines of code. I guess they are not executed. because they were earlier not included in the document.ready callback, and now may be because the execution order is not always correct.